# How can I clear a datatable in asp listview?

Tags: asp.net, listview, datatable

When I use the code below, I remove the datatable values, but the data table structure still exists and displays empty fields (see pics) with the DOM explorer showing an empty table and table rows.

How can I clear the datatable values and the table itself? This way when I repopulate search again, the empty smaller table isn't present?

```
lvwOutput.Items.Clear();

lvwOutput.DataSource = null;

lvwOutput.DataBind();
```

Before

[image: Before]

After items.clear and datasource = null

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property the stores the data table in session that way you can access it during the click event.

```
DataTable dtbleDataSource
{
    get
    {
        return Session["dataSource"] as DataTable
    }
    set
    {
        Session["dataSource"] = value;
    }
}
```

In your click event you can say:

```
dtbleDataSource.Reset();
```

Comment: I can't access the datatable (named dt) in the area of my asp code, it's persisting in the client portion and not the server portion?

Comment: Is there a client side event for the btn click or is it server side only?

Comment: Server side only

Answer (score 0):

This is ridiculous and I believe there is a better way to do this, but the never ending server/client battle makes this harder than it should be. My listview binded to a datatable is called lvwOutput.

In my btnClear I had to put the following. You cannot hide the element or clear the items in the server side asp code for this to work

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "emptyTable", "javascript:emptyTableRows(); ", true);
```

In my javascript code I had to put the following, this clears the client code

```
  function emptyTableRows(){
      var tableHeaderRowCount = 0;
      var table = document.getElementById('lvwOutputTable');
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      for (var i = tableHeaderRowCount; i < rowCount; i++) {
          table.deleteRow(tableHeaderRowCount);
      }
  }
```

And then in the portion of my code that would display the listview and datatable when the user initiates another sql search. This clears the server side.

```
lvwOutput.Items.Clear();
lvwOutput.DataSource = null;
lvwOutput.DataBind();
```